# Python Tableau API what is time() used for HourlyInterval

Tags: python, time, undefined, tableau-api, schedule

Here is a [section of documentation](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#schedulecreate) which shows how to create a new schedule using tableau api.
The problem is that it is saying that a new schedule needs a new interval, e.g. `HourlyInterval` and I have no idea how to create this `HourlyInterval`.
Here is an example from documentation:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
# sign in, etc.
 # Create an interval to run every 2 hours between 2:30AM and 11:00PM
        hourly_interval = TSC.HourlyInterval(start_time=time(2, 30),
                                             end_time=time(23, 0),
                                             interval_value=2)
 # Create schedule item
        hourly_schedule = TSC.ScheduleItem("Hourly-Schedule", 50, TSC.ScheduleItem.Type.Extract, TSC.ScheduleItem.ExecutionOrder.Parallel, hourly_interval)
 # Create schedule
        hourly_schedule = server.schedules.create(hourly_schedule)
```

When I use this example I get an error that time is not defined

```
hourly_interval = TSC.HourlyInterval(start_time=time(2,30), end_time=time(23,0), interval_value=2)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

I don't know what I am missing, I assumed that I need to `import 'time'` but that seems like entirely different library. I have also tried to assign `start_time` or `end_time` in different way but I just got different errors and doc is explicitly saying that this API is expecting this format: `start_time=time(hour, minute)`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
from datetime import time
```

Consider looking into examples, it's a good addition to docs https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/samples/create_schedules.py